# How do I add twitter Oauth Signature to url

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Essentially what I'm looking for is how to get the results like in this API request but by using just a url to make my results appear on a webpage. I think I need to add all of the data in the "request" Tab to the url written at the top of the picture and I'm not really sure how add it correctly:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Twitter's API requires an "Authorization" header in the request.  You can't do it through a URL alone.  See [Authorizing Requests](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests).